# apt thinks python-3.7.3 is the newest version

Tags: python, debian, version, apt, google-chrome-os

I am on a "Linux development environment" on ChromeOS, and I need to install a version of Python later than 3.7.7 to use a package (Since my default python version was 3.7.3).
I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3
```

but got

```
python3 is already the newest version (3.7.3-1).
python3 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

When I tried to install a version higher than 3.7, such as 3.9, I got

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.9'
```

I faced the same exact problem when I used aptitude instead of apt.

I also tried building from source or using ppa(deadsnakes), which seems to be the orthodoxical fix, but neither worked on this device. Could you please help me install a new version using apt or any other package manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install python3.9 through `apt` on debian, you need to upgrade your debian release to `bullseye`.

You can build python3.9 on Debian Buster following [my answer on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332658/153195)

Just replace the `wget` command by:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.5/Python-3.9.5.tar.xz
```